# what is the difference between AppCompatActivity and FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment, appcompatactivity

i am using fragments in my app and i want to change MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity to extends FragmentActivity.what are the major differences between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AppCompatActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`, so anyone who needs to use features of `FragmentActivity` can use `AppCompatActivity`.
`FragmentActivity` is for use with the backport of fragments found in the support-v4 and support-v13 libraries. The native implementation of fragments was added in API Level 11, which is lower than your proposed minSdkVersion values. The only reason why you would need to consider `FragmentActivity` specifically is if you want to use nested fragments (a fragment holding another fragment), as that was not supported in native fragments until API Level 17.

`AppCompatActivity` is from the appcompat-v7 library. Principally, this offers a backport of the action bar. Since the native action bar was added in API Level 11, you do not need `AppCompatActivity` for that. However, current versions of appcompat-v7 also add a limited backport of the Material Design aesthetic, in terms of the action bar and various widgets. There are pros and cons of using appcompat-v7, well beyond the scope of this specific Stack Overflow answer.